# Angular 5 moment-range - typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

Hi I am porting an application from Angular 1 to Angular 5 (Ionic 1 to Ionic 3).

In my Ionic 1 application I am using moment and moment-range

```
var range = moment.range(new Date(2018, 0, 1), new Date(2018, 11, 30));
range.by('days', function (day) {
    // process each day
});
```

I am trying to get this working with typescript.  I am using:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/moment-range

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/moment-range/moment-range-tests.ts

I have the following code from the test code provided by the above link:

```
const range: momentRange.DateRange = new momentRange.DateRange(new Date(2018, 0, 11), new Date(2018, 11, 30));
const it0: Iterable<moment.Moment> = range.by('days');
```

At this point, I am not sure how to iterate over the returned range.by() values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for...of` loop on the resulting `Iterable` object. Something like:

```
const range: momentRange.DateRange = new momentRange.DateRange(new Date(2018, 0, 11), new Date(2018, 11, 30));
const it0: Iterable<moment.Moment> = range.by('days');

for (const day of it0) {
  // do something with each day
}
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting.  I should have put in my initial post that what you proposed was the first thing I tried.  I get the following error on the it0 in the for loop when trying your code - [ts] Type 'Iterable<Moment>' is not an array type or a string type.

Comment: Just a side note, if I comment out the for loop and step through the remaining code it0 is an Object - Symbol(Symbol.iterator):f () but again when I add the for loop in I get an error on the iterator it0 in the for loop.